# ! Missing number, treated as zero., ! Undefined control sequence., ! File ended while scanning use of \pgfmath@dimen@@. LaTex

Tags: pgfplots

i'm trying to graph this function
[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 domain= 0:2,
title= Grafica en LaTex,
    xlabel=$eje x$
    ylabel=$Eje y$
ymin=1, ymax=14,
xmin=1, xmax=1.92,
]
\addplot{(x^{\frac{5}{2}}) + (3x^{\frac{13}{10}}) +2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I keep getting `"Undefined control sequence.", "! File ended while scanning use of \pgfmath@dimen@@."`

Comment: Did [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553469/95441) answer your question? If yes, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). If not, please share more details.

Answer (score 1):

`pgfplots` doesn't use TeX notation for `\addplots`.

Instead use: `\addplot{x^(5/2) + 3*x^(13/10) + 2};`

(Aside: You're missing a commas before and after the `ylabel` too.)